# Windows Will not Start, hangs at "Starting Windows"

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have Ubuntu as the only OS on my netbook, and as a dual-boot on my laptop.

I started a Ubuntu 11.10 CD to burn on Windows and left the house. On my return, I took out the CD, shut down, and went to bed. When I booted up my computer the next morning, it sat there and did nothing at the "Starting Windows" screen.

I waited two hours for it to start and then gave up. I tried Safe Mode but this hangs at Classpnp.sys, and Startup Repair reports that it "cannot fix the problem".

I did a little Internet research and found that it could be fixed by replacing Classpnp.sys. I retrieved the file from another laptop, went into Ubuntu, replaced the file, and restarted. The computer still refused to start.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly did you do there? Did you attempt to install the Ubuntu 11.10 operating system via a CD? Or, were you just burning an .iso image of Ubuntu 11.10 to a CD?

Comment: I just burned an iso of the OS onto a CD.

Comment: Oh, and if this helps, When I run SFC /scannow from startup repair command prompt, it tells me that a update operation is in progress and that I should restart and try again.

Comment: That's so strange. So, you weren't even installing anything. You were just burning an .iso to a CD for install at a later time. Hmmm... How did your computer download Windows updates? Was the setting set to automatic downloads, or did you set it to noify you of updates and you would install them when you choosed? How many files do you have on the laptop? If not many, perhaps you may consider re-installing Windows 7. I believe you have the Recovery Disc. I never save any important docs on internal hard drive just so I can always re-install if I need to. It's saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: I didn't install anything, and I set it to automatic updates so it would stop complaining to me.

Comment: I could reinstall Windows 7, but then I'd have to reinstall everything. If I can get it working without it, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you probably have a corrupted Windows install, probably due to a failing hard drive.

I think your best bet is to get a new disk, rebuild the OS (backups?), and then mount the suspect drive and recover your data.

Comment: No, this laptop is only a couple of weeks old, it shouldn't have any problems.